# Facebook locales in int[] format?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook graph api to post to my Facebook page, and I would like to target the post only to people speaking english.

I have tried this code to set this targeting:

```
$data['targeting'] = "{'locales':'en_US,en_GB,en_IN'}";
```

but I got the error "The targeting param has invalid values for: locales","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"H7e+CSbFZV2"}}"

From the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post , the locales parameter should have the format int[]. Where can I find this list of integers if that's what is required?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish - expand description for parameters targeting or feed_targeting, there's a description how to find the right ids..

Comment: @CBroe thanks, more information is given on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/targeting , but I have tried this request in the API explorer and it's not giving me any result: GET /v2.1/search?type=adlocale&q=en_US HTTP/1.1 what is the correct syntax?

Comment: `search?type=adlocale&q=english`

Comment: thanks a lot it works!